# A question about the proof of the regular value theorem

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I saw the claim, to prove the regular value theorem,  It is enough to show that for every point a of $f^{-1}$(c) there is a neighborhood U of a such that U ∩ $f^{−1}$(c) is a submanifold of U of dimension m − n (where c is the regular point). I wonder how to show this guarantees that $f^{-1}$(c) is a manifold?

Comment: These charts $U \cap f^{-1}(c)$ provide charts for your manifold.

Comment: @MikeMiller As a submanifold, every U has its own atlas, how to show the charts from different U are compatible?